# How to elasticsearch/lucene uses Finite State transducer to make type-ahead/Suggestor search faster

Tags: python, lucene, typeahead, search-suggestion, fst

I am trying to build type-ahead search following data.

```
    ID   DATA STRING
    id_1 "this is line number one"
    id_2 "this is line number two"
```

While querying these data, I will give string like:

```
    "line one" --> output: id_1 (ID of matching string)
    "two line" --> output: id_2
    "this is line num" -->  output id_1 id_2 (multiple results)
```

I tried with inverted index, with n-grams (prefixes), for each token in data string. But for large data-set indexing n-grams is slow (querying is somehow good enough).
Now I got some idea while googling that lucene has Suggester classes which is very fast in type-ahead search and uses FST (Finite State Transducer) to implement fast prefix search.

How can FST be used in my scenario to make type-ahead search faster?